# How to test HashPassword in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, salt, password-hash

I want to test (unit testing) `HashPassword($password)` method from WordPress.

How I can check that HashPassword("123123") will return the correct hash for it?

For example, I want to do something like:

```
$hashFor123123 = "$P$P)230230832482349823";

$result = HashPassword("123123");

$this->assertSame($hashFor123123, $result);
```

But, **HashPassword** method each time returns a new string with hash. That is why I cant do assert.

How to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Password hashing uses a random [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), so each time you hash the same password you'll get a different value back. The theory is explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php), even though WordPress doesn't use the php password hashing functions, but rather their own. You cannot compare hashes; you can only check whether a given unhashed password matches a hash.

The random salt defeats cybercreeps' use of [rainbow lookup tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) to recover passwords given their hashes.  This helps keep your users' passwords secret even if a cybercreep manages to steal your wp_users table. [Defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)), it's called.

In WordPress, you can hash a password and then check it using [wp_hash_password()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_hash_password/) and [wp_check_password(),](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/) something like this.

```php
$hash = wp_hash_password( '123123' );
if ( wp_check_password( '123123', $hash )) {
  /* it worked */
} else {
  /* it did not work */
}
```

It's not clear why it is worth your time to unit-test this subsystem. It is used in production many billions of times every day around the world.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the result is different every time you call `HashPassword` is because your password is [prefixed by a random salt](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/ba943e113d3b31b121f77a2d30aebe14b047c69d/src/wp-includes/class-phpass.php#L152) before it's  hashed.

To compare a plaintext password against a known hash, you have to call `CheckPassword`.